# Qt Translator doesn't work in Lambda Slot

Tags: c++, qt, qtranslator

I try to convince my Qt app to translate the buttons in a dummy dialog. For unknown reason, the first dialog translates to german but the dialog executed in the lambda slot doesn't translate. I already tried to use the older signal syntax to see if the lambda expression was the issue, but it didn't change the outcome. 
After the RTWindow constructor is finished, the application constructor is done and the `main()` calls `app.exec()`. There is no code I have control over that might replaced the translator.

In this code, the callback called by clicking on the menu item creates the untranslated dialog. The dialog created in the constructor is translated.

I don't see

```
RTWindow::RTWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
ui.setupUi(this);



this->setWindowTitle("RodeTracker 2");

auto fileMenu       = new QMenu("Datei");
auto configMenu     = new QMenu("Bearbeiten");
auto clientAction   = new QAction("Kunden ...");

configMenu->addAction(clientAction);

ui.menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);
ui.menuBar->addMenu(configMenu);

// translates fine:
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.exec();

connect(clientAction, &QAction::triggered, [=]()
{
    // doesn't translate:
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel); 
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.exec();
});

}
```

The translation is installed with those lines: (QApplication derivative constructor)

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::German, QLocale::Germany));

QTranslator qtBaseTranslator;
if (qtBaseTranslator.load(QLocale::German, "qtbase", "_", "")) 
{
    installTranslator(&qtBaseTranslator);
    qDebug() << "Base Translator loaded";
}
```

I get the "Base Translator loaded" output. Does anybody know, what might mess with the translation?

Comment: Could you try replacing `[=]()` with `[&]()`? That captures symbols required in the slot by reference instead of copying them. So you might be lucky in case you change translation AFTER RTWindow is constructed.

Comment: That was my first instinct as well but the lambda doesn't really affect the whole situation. Tried it, same result.

Comment: If I got you right the problem is not lambdas. Just to make sure you understand how the translation process works. First you wrap the strings in the code inside the tr functions (like `auto clientAction=new QAction(tr("Clients ..."));`). Then you run lupdate on your project, it looks for tr("...") and creates a ts file where you translate manually strings like "Clients ..." into "Kunden ...". Next you run lrelease on ts and get qm file which you load in QTranslator. I wouldn't mention it if I saw tr/QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP in your code. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html)

Comment: Mhh, it's a small side project and because of time pressure, I'll skip the whole international aspect. All I want is Qt to display the standard buttons (OK, cancel, yes,..) in german. The info I found on the webs is that using translators is the way to go here.

Comment: @ruhig brauner ok, I see now, you load the Qt qml files for German, right? In that case for Qt classes it should work everywhere if it works in one place. Pls update the description to show the place where it doesn't work because the "// doesn't translate" comment  doesn't show the problem.

Comment: @absolute.madness What do you mean? The button's are not translated when this QMessageBox is executed. The exec comes from executing the QAction by clicking the menu entry.

Comment: @ruhigbrauner the description says "the dialog executed in the lambda slot doesn't translate", yet the comment in the lambda says "translates fine", that misled me (sorry, I meant *.qm file in my previous comment, not qml). You could try to subclass QTranslator - qtBaseTranslator in your case, override virtual QTranslator::translate() and check what it gets on input and what returns in both cases (e.g. using qDebug). If you can also debug inside the Qt sources that may give you additional hints as to what happens.

Comment: @absolute.madness Well, I quite obviously goofed up big times. :D Sorry about that, fixed the comment in the source.

Comment: @absolute.madness And the winner is: generating a local variable that is deleted when the constructor of the QApplication derivative is finished. I have nothing to say for my defense. Will write a answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `QTranslator` object needs to exist during the full lifespan of the QApplication. In the example above, generating a translator as a local variable in `QAppDeriv`'s constructor will be fine during the construction but not after that. The correct approach would be to create the `QTranslator` on the heap.

```
QAppDeriv::QAppDeriv(int &argc, char **argv, int flags)
    : QApplication(argc, argv, flags)

{
    // set default local
    QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::German, QLocale::Germany));

    // create translator objects on heap
    QTranslator *qtTranslator = new QTranslator();
    if (qtTranslator->load(QLocale::German, "qt", "_", ""))
    {
        installTranslator(qtTranslator);
    }

    QTranslator *qtBaseTranslator = new QTranslator();
    if (qtBaseTranslator->load(QLocale::German, "qtbase", "_", ""))
    {
        installTranslator(qtBaseTranslator);
    }

    // create the main window
    window  = std::make_shared<RTWindow>();
    window->show();

}
```